# Do else if statements exist in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

I have come across the following code in C#.

```
if(condition0) statement0;
else if(condition1) statement1;
else if(condition2) statement2;
else if(condition3) statement3;
...
else if(conditionN) statementN;
else lastStatement;
```

Some of my colleagues tell me that this is an `else if` statement.  However, I am convinced that it is actually a multi-layered nested `if-else` statement. I know that without delimiters `{}`, one statement is allowed in an `if` or `else`. So in this case I think it would be equivalent to the following code.

```
if(condition0) 
  statement0;
else
  if(condition1)
    statement1;
  else
    if(condition2)
      statement2;
    else
      if(condition3)
        statement3;
      else
      ...
```

Note that all I changed was the whitespace.
This indentation works because each `else` goes back to the most recent `if` statement when there are no delimiters.

Can anyone clarify if the `else if` format in the first example is treated differently by the compiler than the nested `if-else` format in the second example?

Comment: looks like a good case for `switch` :)

Comment: [Language spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx) clears it up in short order. You're right, but it seems a bit of a navel-gazing argument to be having, when it makes no practical difference at all :)

Comment: It's too bad that C# doesn't have macros like C++; My typical solution to this dilemma is to do `#define fandango else if` and then I proceed to write my if-fandango-else statement.  The entire issue of "else-if" is neatly avoided and the code is much more readable. Everyone is aware of the fandango statement, as all they have to do is grep the header files to find the definition in order to read the comment that I associate with it: "// fandango: replaces the "else if" construct".  I'm all about useful comments, obviously.

Comment: Note that if-else-if-else-if-else-if... results in heavily nested scope, at least on some compilers.  I know that in C++, I managed to trigger a nesting compiler error with a (joke) program that had a few hundred else-ifs.  If you're using enough else-ifs to encounter a problem, you probably have bigger problems.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You are correct; there is no such thing as an "else if" statement in C#. It's just an else where the statement of the alternative clause is itself an if statement.

Of course, the *IDE* treats "else if" as special so that you get the nice formatting you'd expect.

Note that there *is* an `#elif` construct in the "preprocessor" syntax.

Note also that C, C++ and ECMAScript - and I am sure many more C-like languages - also have the property that there is no formal "else if" statement. Rather, in each the behaviour falls out of the definition of "else" as coming before a single statement.

Answer (score 4):

It's a multi-layered if-else.

The reason it is has to do with c# syntax rules.  An `else` is followed by a statement, and any `if` chain qualifies as a statement.

Answer (score 4):

The construct `else if` is never mentioned in the [C# specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx), except in some examples where it is used without explanation. So I do not think it is a special construct, it is just nested if statements.

Comment: It is also not listed in the table of keywords (section 2.4.3), which is the formal definition of what constitutes a keyword token.  That's enough for me, but to take it a bit further: A keyword is described as "an identifier-like sequence of characters"; the specification for identifiers does not allow whitespace characters.  Since "else if" contains at least one whitespace character, I would say that it is not "an identifier-like sequence of characters".

Comment: @Dr. Wily: in much the same way `yield return` is not a keyword according to the spec. But it still has meaning.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.  It's just an `else` followed by an `if`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "else if" statement in C#.

For that matter, I don't know that there are *any* multi-word statement keywords in C#.

Comment: yield return. yield break.

Comment: Well, It's say `foreach..in` is a multi-word keyword, albeit broken up a bit.

Comment: `yield return` would be a multi-word statement keyword.  As would `foreach (... in ...)`, depending on how loosely you want to interpret the phrase.

Comment: `yield return` is not a single keyword.  It is a contextual keyword followed by the required context keyword `return` or `break`;

Comment: try-catch-finally. do-while. switch-case.

Comment: @Eric: thanks. You're right, of course. No matter what it actually is in terms of the compiler grammar, "yield break" is conceptually the same kind of thing as "else if" would be, if that were a statement.

Answer (score 1):

The [Selection Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664745(v=VS.71).aspx) of the C# Language Specification only shows `if` and `switch` statements.  If you select the `if` statement, it says:

> The if statement selects a statement for execution based on the value of a Boolean expression.
>
> if-statement:
>
> if   (   boolean-expression   )   embedded-statement
>
> if   (   boolean-expression   )   embedded-statement   else   embedded-statement
>   boolean-expression:
>   expression
>
> An else part is associated with the lexically nearest preceding if that is allowed by the syntax

Answer (score 1):

The two examples you give are equivalent in every language. In C or C#, it's exactly equivalent to an else, then if. In some other languages, elseif is syntactic sugar for else, then if. So no matter which language you use, they will compile to the same code (or be interpreted to the same behavior). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_%28programming%29#Else_If

Comment: In general, "else if" is treated as two separate statements by a compiler/interpreter. Languages with an "else if" construct usually use a single word, such as elseif or elif.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @hunter's answer the reason, as you hit on it that without brackets it will only execute the next line, if it were a bunch of nested the else would need brackets:

```
if(condition0) 
  statement0;
else
{
  if(condition1)
    statement1;
  else
  {
    if(condition2)
      statement2;
    else
    {
      if(condition3)
        statement3;
      else
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Down vote for explaining the brackets, which is what he thought was happening?

Comment: The issue is that else-if *is* a nested if-else structure and you don't actually need the brackets (not that they wouldn't be encouraged if actually written in a new line + indented style). Brackets are not about *lines*, they are about *statements*. The statement, in this case, is another *if*.

Comment: Agree completely, I was more stating where his original thought was incorrect, and if it was as he thought it would need to be as I wrote it.